# How to clear or limit groovy "memoize" cache size?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, dynatrace

We are using Groovy/Grail, XML and XSLT and mostly using groovy **Closures** for iteration on parsed XML by XmlParser/XmlSlurper (**Node API**). Deployment Env - JRE 8, Tomcat 8.

But facing high CPU usage by **"org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize"** package. Its almost 2 GB size used by this cache. (we are not using memoize() function/annotation in code.)

We didn't found anything helpful on google to clear or limit cache.
Can anyone help in this? - Thanks

Comment: Looks like some closures using memoize, I am afraid, the only option is to restart the jvm

Comment: Thanks Sudhir, we are now restarting VM for every week.
Is there way to recognize which closure is using memoize? by Dynatrace or any other tool.

Comment: Any closure using .memoize() can be replaced with .memoizeAtMost(maxCacheSize) if you need to delimit it. However, you would need to find it first. Secondly, if you are seeing high CPU usage, it is probably a good reason to have memoize for repeated request in the first case, and removing it may actually end up lowering the throughput...

Comment: BTW, also look for @Memoized annotation, which can have maxCacheSize attribute as well.

Comment: Thanks  Niels Bech Nielsen, as of now I am are not using memoize() anywhere in code, it looks like automatically some closures using memoize cache .. my challenge is to recognize those and add memoizeAtMost(size) limit, but how we can recognize those?